# PHP Configuration File

Tags: php, web-applications, configuration

What would be a better option for creating a configuration file?
Parsing a config.ini or 
requiring a config.php containing an array of configurations?

Comment: Depends, very vague question.

Comment: "what's better, black or white?" All depends on context. A black polar-bear would be seen by prey and starve to death. A white 'black-bear' would be laughed at by his friends

Comment: config.php would be faster because it has not to parse the ini file.

Comment: you can create a custom ini in php refer this http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: well to be specific, in terms of framework performance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A config.php file is better, because there is no compilation required since it's native php code.  I would also point out that ini files support sections and key value pairs, and anything that requires a more deeply nested hierarchy can't be expressed in the ini format.

Some people are concerned about the security issues involved but the security of a site is already a complex task with a number of different intrinsic approaches.

FWIW, you left out yaml and xml as alternatives for configuration that are supported by a number of frameworks and there are libraries to handle each of them.

Comment: +1 for also mentioning yaml and xml.